# Jenkins plugin for different types of slaves

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have some tests that need to be run on multiple types of specific hardware.  Its possible that these tests might pass on some pieces of hardware but fail on others, and we want to know where they work and where they fail.

So, for certain tests, we would like to provide a list of hardware they need to be tested on.  We'd like to put all the needed hardware in a pool that Jenkins has access to, and then have Jenkins run the right tests on the right hardware, depending on the hardware list that comes with the test.  And of course we'd like to keep track of which test worked where.

Is there a plugin for Jenkins to be able to handle this sort of thing?  Has anyone else solved this sort of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign label values to the slaves to indicate the type of hardware, then restrict the jobs to only run on slaves that use those labels, you should get the desired result.